# Crosswalk: how to get URL of non-web resource opened in new tab/window

Tags: android, crosswalk-runtime

Let's say my Crosswalk view in my Android activity is showing a page like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<a target="_blank" href='http://some-website.com/document.pdf'>Download a PDF</a>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I intercept the URL of that link?

Note that because it is opening the link in a new "window", the callbacks like `XWalkResourceClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading` or `shouldInterceptLoadRequest` are not called, probably because Crosswalk is loading an entirely new document.

There is a callback for window creation, `XWalkUIClient.onCreateWindowRequested`, but that doesn't contain any parameter that contains the URL that is being loaded in the new window.

I'm also aware that, when a new window is created, the user code can instantiate a new XWalkView to be used to load the destination document, and I should set the custom resource client and UI client.

What I tried so far:

- All methods in `XWalkResourceClient` and `XWalkUIClient` with a URL parameter, in both the origin and destination views. Either they are not called, or the parameter is null or empty;
- In `XWalkUIClient.onCreateWindowRequested`, return a subclass of XWalkView that overrides `load()` so it can intercept the url. That method is not called.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure override shouldOverrideUrlLoading will intercept the url in your html.
I did nothing special, and add code like below:

```
  mXWalkView.setResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(mXWalkView) {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(XWalkView view, String url) {
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading  ");
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        }
  });
```

And then load the html you provide:

```
mXWalkView.load("file:///android_asset/download.html", null);
```

When I click the link in the XWalkView, shouldOverrideUrlLoading will be called and the UI like below，

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to activate this when an a href link is clicked in the Crosswalk Webview? If yes, how?

Comment: My sample in above is the Crosswalk WebView.